# Android layout, how to position two images and an seekbar

Tags: android, layout, seekbar

## What I want to achieve

I'm trying to make a layout  equal to the next link:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/59647462@N08/7038207573/

## What I have

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/minVolume"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_min" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/maxVolume"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_max" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the result I'm getting with this code that the seekbar extends over the right icon.

- I would like to have it scaled appropriately on different screenszes
- If its possible without using the weight attribute, i would love that solution

any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a relative layout and make the left image anchored to the left side (ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT), the right image anchored to the right side (ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT) and the seekbar between them with android:layout_toRightOf and android:layout_toLeftOf.

For more info see the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: This was the best solution in my oppinion, what I was looking for, thx Moss

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:layout_weight="0.9"` in SeekBar. **or**

Without using **layout_weight**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/minVolume"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_min" />    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/maxVolume"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_volume_max"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />    
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user1281750 if you didn't got answer, check my updated answer, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set layout_width to 0 for all the three widgets and weight to 1 for the seekbar that should  work. I don't know how to do that without weight (and why?)

Comment: Thank you for answering, really like your approach. the reason i asked without weight, was to see what others ways would be possible for laying out an layout ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the windowManager to get the size and then adjust using operators like '/' etc,

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();
int width = display.getWidth();
```

Although i believe newer API has come into force.